# Is there a way to reference a kendo window by class instead of ID?

Tags: jquery, kendo-asp.net-mvc

The title pretty much says it all. I added a class to a Kendo Window like so (trying to make it generic)

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("modal")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "kendo-modal" })
    .Visible(false)
    .Modal(true))
```

I can't seem to reference it with jQuery. When I try to do this

```
$(".kendo-modal").data("kendoWindow").close();
```

I get a "cannot read property 'close' of null" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So...putting the class in the cshtml code didn't work

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("modal")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "kendo-modal" })
    .Visible(false)
    .Modal(true))
```

Adding it to the modal in javascript worked

```
$("#modal").addClass("kendo-modal").data("kendoWindow")
     .title("Add Comment")
     .refresh().center().open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally If you have a selector inside the window since I am guessing this is what you want to do, (probably on button click of a button that is inside the window close this window) you could use the closest k-window to find the correct element

```
$( buttonInsideWindow ).closest(".k-window-content").data("kendoWindow").close();
```

This is quite helpful just to keep in mind.